# Using Kal calendar from existing table view and popToRootViewController not working

Tags: ios, popviewcontroller

I'm trying use Kal calendar in my project.  Here is what I understand to be the case so far:

- Whichever view controller that calls Kal must implement the UITableViewDelegate method "didSelectRowAtPath"

Issue:

- My view controller that calls Kal *already* has an existing tableview (one of the cells would call Kal)

To solve this, I've attempted to push an intermediary view controller from a cell in my main tableview as follows:

```
ScheduleViewController *svc = [[ScheduleViewController alloc] init];
[svc setTitle:@"Schedule"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

From ScheduleViewController's viewDidLoad, I'm pushing the actual Kal calendar:

```
KalViewController *kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
[kal setDelegate:self];
[kal setTitle:@"Schedule"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:kal animated:NO];
```

So once I do this, I can get the calendar to show up.  However, I can't seem to cleanly get back to my main menu using the back button.  I created a back button in ScheduleViewController:

```
[kal.navigationItem
setBackBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                    target:self
                                                    action:@selector(test)]];
```

I've put this in a few different places (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear) and can't get it to work.  When I click "Back" it still goes to ScheduleViewController instead of all the way back.  "test" never gets called.  I've tried popToRootViewController, [[self.presentingViewController presentingViewController] dismissViewController], and a few others.  Just doesn't want to work.

- Is this the best way to go about using Kal?
- How can I popToRootViewController (skipping ScheduleViewController) using this method?

Thanks!  This is my first post so please let me know if there's anything I can do to make the question less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally got it I think.  I ended up removing the intermediary view controller.  I think I just didn't understand what was going on earlier...I've now done the following:

- instead of my main view controller (w/the existing tableview) being the delegate, I made the KalDataSource also be the UITableViewDelegate.  So my DataSource handles both populating the calendar and selection of an event.
- added id datasource as in ivar in main view controller
- changed the "didSelectRowAtPath" method to:

  dataSource = [[EventsDataSource alloc] init];

  KalViewController *kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
  [kal setDelegate:dataSource];
  [kal setDataSource:dataSource];
  [kal setTitle:@"Schedule"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:kal animated:YES];

Everything now *appears* to be okay.